# Laravel loading page from DB trans function not working

Tags: php, laravel, content-management-system, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm storing pages dynamically in my database (pages table).

When I store blade function like `{{ trans('langfile.key') }}` in my database and then present it in my view, blades `{{}}` functions are not triggered. Any ides on how to accomplish this?

Table row

```
1   test    This is our test title  {{ trans('commons.mobile') }}   2016-10-06 08:37:49 2016-10-06 08:42:48
```

Controller

```
 public function show(Request $request, $slug){

        $page= DB::table('pages')->where('slug', $slug)->first();
        return View::make('page')->with('page', $page->page_content);
    }
```

View

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

    <div class="container contentpadding"></div>

    {!! $page !!}
@stop
```

Result is `{{ trans('commons.mobile') }}` and not Mobile (if lang = us)

Comment: This is because blade parses {!! $page !!} to echo $page;, in which case blade functionalities and syntaxes are not parsed again. The best way to make this work is either parse the content yourself, using the Blade fascade, but this might be tricky. Better practise could be using a package like this: http://github.com/Flynsarmy/laravel-db-blade-compiler good luck!

Comment: Thanks! If anybody else is wondering i also found a Blade function called Blade::compileString. Then get the html from there. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/render-template-from-blade-template-in-database helped me out.